# Getting Network-related error Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, iis-6, windows-server-2008-r2, general-network-error

I am trying to setup my application on a server.
Below are the server configuration details:

- Windows server 2008 R2
- SQL server 2008 R2

Application which will run on Application pools v4.0 .net framework; Integrated and using `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.

IIS 6.0

I have created a site in IIS and also kept a build of asp.net application on server and attached to IIS site.

We have set our database on the same server.

Site is up. I am getting login page. But when I am trying  to login the application, it is giving me below yellow screen error:
[image: Error Image]

Below is the connection string I have used in my application:

```
<connectionStrings>
            <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Database;User Id=User1; Password=Admin@123;Connection Timeout=100" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
            <add name="BusinessEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BusinessEntities.csdl|res://*/BusinessEntities.ssdl|res://*/BusinessEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Database;persist security info=True;User Id=User1; Password=Admin@123;Connection Timeout=180;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>       
      </connectionStrings>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Am I missing any extra setting?

Comment: Your app is trying to connect to SQL Server instance running on localhost(.) so is it intended? If yes, ensure that SQL Server Service is up and running on the server.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood: Yes it is intented. I even tried using server name, ., (local) but its of no use. I also checked SQL server service is up and running on the server. Even I ave checked TCP/IP protocol also. It is enabled